# Let go of or let go

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is correct? And do they have different meanings?

1. Please let go of her.
2. Please let her go.

Answer (score 3):

They are both grammatical but show up in slightly different usages:

1. "Let go of *someone*" implies that someone is being *physically* held, as in directly restrained by hand.
2. "Let *someone* go" could include a physical restraint, but could also refer to a any other sense of captivity or preventing from departure. It can also be metaphorical, suggesting that one be relieved of a relationship or job or other connection.